# How could I define a safe division using interface and reflect?

Tags: go

I want to define a safe division like:

```golang
func safeDivide(a, b interface{}) interface{} {
    if b == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return a / b
}
```

Obviously, this function does not work. we can not divide interface. One solution is to judge the type of input and do the division.

```golang
switch reflect.ValueOf(x).Kind() {
    case reflect.Int:
    // balabala...
```

However it looks redundadnt, I must deal every case.

So if I could use reflect to guarantee the type of inputs? I have tried reflect.TypeOf() but failed.

By the way, I notice this:

```golang
a := uint32(0)
ifZero(a) // outputs "no"

func ifZero(a interface{}) {
    if a == 0 {
        log.Println("yes")
        return
    }
    log.Println("no")
}
```

That means golang itself cannot deal the type issue, right?

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection? A simple type switch seems much more logical.

Comment: And yes, whether you use type assertions or reflections, you will have a lot of redundant code. Go doesn't support generics.

Comment: prefer type switch for automatic code optimization by the compiler. Even with reflect you will have to perform some kind of type assertions, so its not interesting in that case.

Comment: @Flimzy Then I know why we need generics, thank you.

Comment: Well, I know why some people want generics. I still dread the day they're added to the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441284/how-could-i-define-a-safe-division-using-interface-and-reflect#comment101360234_57441284), now you know why (some) people want generics in Go. :-)

For this particular case, you're probably better off just writing a `safeDivideInt` function:

```
// a/b, but 0 if b == 0
func safeDivideInt(a, b int64) int64 {
    if b == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return a / b
}
```

and a similar `safeDivideUint` function (using `uint64`) ... and, if you need it,<sup>1</sup> a `safeDivideFloat` function, e.g.:

```
func safeDivideFloat(a, b float64) float64 {
    // decide if you want 0/0 handled differently
    // decide if you want to check for b being Inf or NaN
    // etc.
    if b == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return a / b
}
```

and then yet again for complex, if you want.

But: there's no easy way to make the Go compiler call one or the other for you.  You can write your interface-based function the way you did, and then do type-switching on the various arguments, but it gets quite long as you have to handle all possible combinations.  The combinatorial effect is painful no matter how you reduce it.  Using `reflect` and its type-kind interface does not help here as you still have five `int` types, five `uint` types (or six if you include `uintptr`), the two `float` types, and the two `complex` types.  (It's not clear to me that allowing either of the `Uintptr` or `UnsafePointer` `Kind`s in your divide function makes any sense at all.)

It might, however, make more sense—depending on context—to define your own interface.  [Here's a working toy example on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nNF7hcOJUxy).  I didn't bother putting in Uint and Complex types.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that a runtime 1.0 / 0.0 is `+Inf`.  The [Go specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) says:

> The result of a floating-point or complex division by zero is not specified beyond the IEEE-754 standard; whether a run-time panic occurs is implementation-specific.

but IEEE-754 calls for Inf and NaN results by default, with exceptions being optional, so I assume this means that the default in Go is no exception raised, meaning "no panic", as well.  See, e.g., [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Dealing_with_exceptional_cases) from which I quote a bit here:

> Arithmetic exceptions are (by default) required to be recorded in "sticky" status flag bits. ... By default, an operation always returns a result according to specification without interrupting computation. For instance, 1/0 returns +∞, while also setting the divide-by-zero flag bit (this default of ∞ is designed so as to often return a finite result when used in subsequent operations and so be safely ignored).